# Magento2 get payment options on cart page

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, payment-methods

How can i get payment methods on cart page where user can select payment option before moving to checkout page. **magento2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code to get **Payment method**

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use \Magento\Payment\Model\Config;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface,
        Config $paymentModelConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface = $appConfigScopeConfigInterface;

        $this->_paymentModelConfig = $paymentModelConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getPaymentMethod()
    {  
        $payments = $this->_paymentModelConfig->getActiveMethods();
        $methods = array();
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel) {
            $paymentTitle = $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface
                ->getValue('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
            $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
                'label' => $paymentTitle,
                'value' => $paymentCode
            );
        }
        return $methods;
    }
```